# Cause exception while process update id=140973171 by bot id=6692283906 TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method

Tags: python-3.x

I decided to make the first bot for downloading videos from YouTube, it connected to the /start command, but it doesn’t download the video, and there are no errors

I tried to change the filter but it seems to me the problem is in the YouTube library

```
import yt_dlp
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
from aiogram import html
TOKEN = ('6692283906:AAG6QYii4BPR6iqUVPOlfgxkAWqirIwth0k')
bot = Bot(TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()

def get_direct_link(video_url):
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720]',
        'quiet': True,
        'no_warnings': True,
        'outtmpl': '%(id)s.%(ext)s',
        'merge_output_format': 'mp4'
        }

    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info_dict = ydl.extract_info(video_url, download=False)
    L = info_dict['formats']
    for x in range(len(L)):
        if L[x].get('height', 0) == 1280:
            direct_link = L[x]['url']
            return direct_link

async def keep_alive():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

@dp.message(F.text == '/start')
async def handler(message):
    await message.reply('Просто напиши мне ссылку на видео youtube, а я скачаю его для тебя)')


@dp.message (F.text.startswith('https...youtu.be/', 'https...youtube.com/'))
async def handler(message):
    url = str(message.text)
    direct_link = get_direct_link(url)
    text = html.link('Вот, лови', html.quote(direct_link))
    await message.answer(text, parse_mode="HTML")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(keep_alive())
    loop.create_task(dp.start_polling(bot, skip_updates=True))
    loop.run_forever()
```